# Parsing one element with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I´m trying to do something which should be very simple.
I want to mail my clients a link which i get from a automatically made XML file.
I´m trying to get it using SimpleXML but I just can´t get it working. This is the code I use, $betaal should give me the link which is in the  in the XML

```
$source = 'https://www.mollie.nl/xml/ideal?a=create-link&partnerid=1036301&amount=$total&description=$naam';
$betaallink  = simplexml_load_string($source);
$betaal = $betaallink->response->link->URL;
```

The XML can be for example this one: https://www.mollie.nl/xml/ideal?a=create-link&partnerid=1036301&amount=28099&description=HPH

Thank you!

Edit1:

Okay I tried the load function option, but it still don't work. Maybe the error is somewhere else? This is a bigger part of the code, but in the mail the $betaal doesn't show the link which I try to get out of the XML file.

```
$source = 'https://www.mollie.nl/xml/ideal?a=create-link&partnerid=1036301&amount=28099&description=HPH';
$betaallink  = simplexml_load_file($source);
$betaal = $betaallink->response->link->URL;

$email = "info@email.nl";
$subject = "Subscription";
$message = "Pay here: $betaal";
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: The response from that xml is totally different then the object you are trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

Use simplexml_load_file function instead:
https://php.net/manually/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

The simplexml_load_string function receives the xml content not a path/url, for your particular case you are providing a file url, so simplexml_load_file must be used.